# RDS 2012R2 not reconnecting to disconnected session from RDWeb

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds, rdweb

When a user connects via RDWeb and closes all the applications, the session is disconnected. If that same user, then connects via RDP to the full desktop, a new session is created instead of reconnecting the disconnected session from RDWeb.

Aside from bringing a continuity issue, it also breaks mapped drives.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: AFAIK, it isn't possible to connect to the same session. The web and desktop sessions are managed by two different hosts (services hosting the sessions).

Comment: Crap. That's a bad design. On top of that, there seem to be no way to log off of an RDWeb session.

Comment: Agreed, one would think there are enough similarities that the sessions could use the same interfaces/base classes and allow integrated management by a single process.

Comment: dartonw: make your first comment an answer and I'll validate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design, RDWeb and full RDP session are using different services.